# Android: Installing new HelloWorld application, reset some application icons

Tags: android, sdk, icons

I've followed the Android SDK tutorial to create an HelloWorld application and installed on my HTC.

However, for some reason, some other application icons on the 'desktop' have been reset to the default 'green droid' icon (disappeared).
It happens for the following Market apps: "Cube calculator", "Barr". Only some apps are infected. (All of the HTC apps, Twiter,  ES File explorer, Note Everything,...ect are fine)

Any idea what the fix for this is?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall your application, reset your HTC device and reinstall your application. Does it still occur?